# apache ignite SQL query too slow

Tags: sql, performance, ignite

3 node cluster.
Each node has 2 * L5520 physical processor,and 64GB memory,1TB HDD

I used `COPY FROM ... FORMAT CSV` import the data to the ignite,Now I execute SQL query in the JDBC console, it's so slow. Can someone tell me any optimizations?

[image]

Comment: 0: jdbc:ignite:thin://xx> select count(1) from x_jjhk;
+--------------------------------+
|            COUNT(1)            |
+--------------------------------+
| 9176749                        |
+--------------------------------+
1 row selected (89.305 seconds)

Comment: select sum(t0.wd) as wd_s,count(distinct case when t0.jjhklb in ('03','04') then t0.nbxh end) as nbxh_t,count(distinct case when t0.jjhklb in ('01','02') then t0.zch end) as zch_t,count(distinct case when t0.jjhklb in ('07') then t0.zs2 end) as sz2_t
from x_jjhk t0
left join x_szpc t1
on (t0.djjg = t1.code)
WHERE (T1.sz_pid0='420000' and t1.sz_pid3 like '421%' and 
    T0.HZRQQ < TO_TIMESTAMP('20160412', 'yyyymmdd') AND
    T0.HZRQZ >= TO_TIMESTAMP('20160411', 'yyyymmdd') AND
    (T0.JYFW LIKE '%批发%' OR T0.JYFW LIKE '%农%' OR
    T0.JYFW LIKE '%建筑%')).  1 row selected (169.206 seconds)

Comment: I don't see indexes configured. Please update your question with execution plan.

Answer (score 0):

you are missing indices on cache.

```
                         <property name="indexes">
                                <list>
                                    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.cache.QueryIndex">
                                        <constructor-arg value="xyzFromKeyorVal"/>
                                    </bean>

                                </list>
                            </property>
```

Add above property to cacheConfiguration. This 'xyzFromKeyorVal' is nothing but any property from key or value object that you want to put index on.